# Make \part in scrartcl

Tags: sectioning, koma-script, parts

I am using the `scrartcl` of well-known [KOMA-script](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/koma-script/) (to those that know it well). As you know the article class has an environment called **Abstract**. Great, I like this and I use it. However, what I actually a making (and I have asked many questions here about the same and I am sorry I do not really answer questions because I am way more incompetent than the people that can actually answer them. Perhaps soon after I learn more!)

What I have is an document called `Puzzles.tex` that is basically a template for each puzzle which is in a `<description of puzzle>.tex` file. Great!

However, I also have different categories of these puzzles. What I would like is a page in between that states say: *APPLES!!* for problems related to apples. That could be named I. APPLES!! on the page and for the rest an empty pagestyle (or whatever). The next files are included and the title is a `section` and the parts are `subsections`.

**Summary:**
So, basically the problem is: How do I make a `\part` for the scrartcl class? I also would like to have it in the TOC. Another option would be to implement an abstract in the book class (and then do section -> chapter and subsection -> section), but using the book class seems weird as I probably have less than 30 pages.

Any option that would give me what I need would be interesting, even the ones I did not mention. My ignorance can contribute to the fact that I miss better solutions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The command `\part` is already implemented in the `scrartcl` document class, so you can just redefine how this command behaves. You can redefine `\partheadstartvskip`, `\partheadmidtvskip`, and `\partheadstartvskip` so that `\part` titles for `scrartcl` are typeset in their own page using, for example, the `empty` pagestyle. Redefining `\raggedpart` (used in `scrartcl.cls` to have raggedright title for parts) to be `\centering`, you will get centered titles:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\renewcommand\partheadstartvskip{\clearpage\null\vfil}
\renewcommand\partheadmidvskip{\par\nobreak\vskip 20pt\thispagestyle{empty}}
\renewcommand\partheadendvskip{\vfil\clearpage}
\renewcommand\raggedpart{\centering}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\part{Test Part}
\section{Test Section}

\end{document}
```

An image of the first two pages:

[image]

Since the page style for the modified `\part` pages was declared to be empty, it doesn't make sense to have a page numbers for the ToC entries associated to `\part`; to suppress the page number in the ToC, you can add to the preamble the following lines:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\l@part}{\hss#2}{}{}{}
\makeatother
```

If you want to suppress the word "Part" from the title, simply add to the preamble the line

```
\renewcommand*\partformat{\thepart\autodot}
```

Here's an example illustrating the suggested modifications:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\l@part}{\hss#2}{}{}{}
\makeatother

\renewcommand\partheadstartvskip{\clearpage\null\vfil}
\renewcommand\partheadmidvskip{\par\nobreak\vskip 20pt\thispagestyle{empty}}
\renewcommand\partheadendvskip{\vfil\clearpage}
\renewcommand\raggedpart{\centering}
\renewcommand*\partformat{\thepart\autodot}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\part{Apples}
\section{Test Apple Section}

\end{document}
```

And the image of the first two pages:

[image]