# How to create a part?

Tags: sectioning

I am using `scrartcl` and I want to create a part in the center of a page like this

[image]

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `\part` sectioning command and since you need parts and likely have a bigger document I’d say it is better to use `scrbook` or `scrartcl`:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{xcolor}

% roman numbering
\renewcommand{\thepart}{\Roman{part}}
% remove dot after number
\renewcommand{\partformat}{\partname~\thepart}
% font for "Part X"
\setkomafont{partnumber}{\normalsize\rmfamily}
% font for part title
\setkomafont{part}{\Large\rmfamily\color{red}\MakeUppercase}

\begin{document}
\part{Beautiful result}
Test
\end{document}
```

If you want a part page in `scrartcl` see [Make \part in scrartcl](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/64215/4918).

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you need,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}


\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\null\vfill
\begin{center}
\textbf{Part II} \\ \vspace{1\baselineskip}
\textcolor{red}{\textbf{BEAUTIFUL RESULTS}}
\end{center}
\vfill\clearpage

\end{document}
```

You may see this [question.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70714/center-horizontally-and-vertically-a-block-of-text)

Comment: I thin this is not a good solution, since it is fully manual. What if the order of the part changes? What if you want to change the layout of the parts later? What if you want them in the ToC. I’d say it’s way better to use the appropriate sectioning command `\part` and adapt the layout (see my answer).

Comment: @ddas: But I need this to appear on the content section. Do you have any idea?

Comment: yes @Tobi you are absolutely right. @Sucre you should try @Tobi 's answer. There you can add the command `\tableofcontents` after `\begin{document}` to get it in the content section.